# Line Simplification image processing

Tags: algorithm, matlab, image-processing

I am trying to use `douglas-peucker` algorithm to simplify my connected components.I get my connected components using `bwlabel` and I send it to the `douglas` algorithm.Here is the link of the algorithm which I am using-
[Douglas-Peucker Algorithm matlab](http://in.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/21132-line-simplification/content/dpsimplify.m)

Here is my code-

```
clc;
image=imread('mmm1.jpg');
image = im2bw(image);

[imx imy]=size(image);
n1=zeros(imx,imy);
I=zeros(imx,imy);
L = bwlabel(image,8) ;%Calculating connected components
[r,c] = find(L==1);        %Using 1st connected component
n1=zeros(imx,imy);
rc = [r c];

[ps mm]     = dpsimplify(rc,1);          %Douglas-Peucker algorithm

 %To display original component 
%___________________________________________________________________  
[sx sy]=size(rc);
for j=1:sx
    x1=rc(j,1);
    y1=rc(j,2);
    n1(x1,y1)=1;
end
figure,imshow(n1);
%___________________________________________________________________
 %To display component after simplification 
 n1=zeros(imx,imy);
 [sx sy]=size(mm);
 for j=1:sx
    x1=rc(j,1);
    y1=rc(j,2);
    n1(x1,y1)=1;
 end
 figure,imshow(n1);
```

This was my original input image-
[image]

This was my `1st` component to which I applied `Douglas-Peucker` algorithm-

[image]

This was the result of algorithm-
[image]

The code of Douglas-Peucker can be found in the link I mentioned above.So,**My question is** why is the simplification not happening for the entire component?How can I fix this?

Comment: I guess because you need points or lines that describe the "line", not pixels. Try to obtain the skeleton of your image first. https://uk.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/bwmorph.html

Comment: PD: Why would you like to simplify those lines? What do you expect? The are as simple as they can get.

Comment: @AnderBiguri This is because when I run `corner detection algorithm` many of the slanted lines in this image which are not simplified enough they give wrong result.Corner detection fails to run in these images as it detects way too many corner points

Comment: Then what you want is the morphological skeleton of you image! (I think)

Comment: @AnderBiguri I tried the skeleton of the image using `bwmorph` I get identical result as above

Comment: The exact result? I doubt it!

Comment: @AnderBiguri Yes I did the skeleton of the image before finding the components.Then after that I called the douglas-peucker algorithm using component of the skeletonized image.Same result

Comment: Oh yeah! I mean, you may JUST want the skeleton and not use the douglas-peuker. With the skeleton you shoudl be able to detect corners better, if thats your ultimate goal. Anyway, I am not an expert, maybe someone else can help

Comment: Hi! I've made a chatroom for us so we can discuss things related to MATLAB that may be off-topic, or spans longer than what can be placed in a comments box.  Come visit when you have time! http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81987/matlab

Answer (score 2):

I believe you want to identify how many straight line segments are there in the image. I did something similar to morphological hit and was able to segment these lines, though not in their full length.

I prepared a vertical line structuring element (SE), then created another two SEs by rotating it by 60 and 120 degrees about its center. I eroded the original image with these SEs and then obtained the connected components.

```
im = imread('IWVlt.jpg');
bw = im2bw(im, graythresh(im));

% SEs
w = 15;
line = zeros(w);
line(:, round(w/2)) = 1;

bw1 = zeros(size(bw));

for i = 1:3
    bw1 = bw1 + imerode(bw, line);
    line = imrotate(line, 60, 'nearest');
end

[lbl, n] = bwlabel(bw1, 8);

figure, imshow(bw1)
figure, imshow(label2rgb(lbl))
```

As the result I get 25 components. By varying w in the code you can minimize the error.
[image: bonds]

For w = 9 which is the lowest value w can take while detecting all segments, I get 26 components. You can filter out components that are too small.
[image: bonds2]

Comment: Hi! I've made a chatroom for us so we can discuss things related to MATLAB that may be off-topic, or spans longer than what can be placed in a comments box.  Come visit when you have time! http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81987/matlab